# how set session for wtforms-alchemy when I using flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I`m using flask-sqlalchemy and init SQLAlchemy() in my application by init_app() like this :

```
in config file :

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///example.db'
---------------------    
in extension file :

from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
---------------------
in application file: 

#in my application file that generate my app
from ----- import db 

db.init_app(app)
```

my model is :

```
from -------- import db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True , primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50),unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50),unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

now when i using wtforms-alchemy in my form.py like this :

```
from wtforms_alchemy import ModelForm

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

i have this error :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wtforms_components/validators.py", line 220, in _check_for_session
raise Exception('Could not obtain SQLAlchemy session.')

Exception: Could not obtain SQLAlchemy session.
```

How can i fix this bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [WTForms-Alchemy advanced section](http://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#using-wtforms-alchemy-with-flask-wtf):

> In order to make WTForms-Alchemy work with Flask-WTF you need the following snippet:
>
> ```
> from flask.ext.wtf import Form
> from wtforms_alchemy import model_form_factory
>
> ModelForm = model_form_factory(Form)
> ```
>
> The you can use the ModelForm just like before:
>
> ```
> class UserForm(ModelForm):
>     class Meta:
>         model = User
> ```

This *does* rely on `User` having a `.query` object; e.g. your `User` model must be derived from `db.Model`. If it doesn't then you need to define `get_session` method *on the form*:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_session(self):
        return db.session
```

Comment: Thanx about your answer but my problem is sqlalchemy session.

Comment: @sdnaghdi: all that WTForms-Alchemy `Unique` validators do is look for `User.query`; if that doesn't exist then you need to add a  `get_session()` method. It most likely means that you didn't use `db.Model` for your `User` model.